# The actionButton works when I use only one data but it doesn't work when I use 2 data in shiny

Tags: r, button, shiny

I used shiny to create a web.

When I use only a set of data, the actionButton really works well.

But when I divide the data into 2 pieace, th button doesn't work anymore. And the plot will appear at once when I input a gene symbol without th actionButton.

And I tried many methods but I don't know where is wrong with my data or codes.

Can somebody help me ?

```
 library(shiny)
    library(ggplot2)
    
    mean_data <- data.frame(
      Name = c(paste0("Group_", LETTERS[1:20])),
      matx <- matrix(sample(1:1000, 1000, replace = T), nrow = 20)
    )
    names(mean_data)[-1] <- c(paste0("Gene_", 1:50))
    
    sd_data <- data.frame(
      Name = c(paste0("Group_", LETTERS[1:20])),
      matx <- matrix(runif(1000, 5, 10), nrow = 20)
    )
    names(sd_data)[-1] <- c(paste0("Gene_", 1:50))
    
    # Prepare dataset.
    #   1. Bind mean and sd data
    #   2. Reshape
    data <- bind_rows(list(
      mean = mean_data,
      sd = sd_data
    ), .id = "stat")
    data_mean_sd <- data %>%
      pivot_longer(-c(Name, stat), names_to = "Gene", values_to = "value") %>%
      pivot_wider(names_from = "stat", values_from = "value")
    ###
    ui <- fluidPage(
      fluidRow(
        column(8,offset = 3,
               h2("Gene_FPKM Value Barplot")
        )
      ),
      fluidRow(
        column(8,offset = 3,
               selectInput(
                 "selectGeneSymbol", 
                 "Select Gene Symbol:", 
                 choices = unique(data_mean_sd$Gene),
                 multiple =F,
                 width = 800,
                 selected = "Igfbp7"
               ))
      ),
      fluidRow(
        column(8,offset = 3,
               actionButton(inputId = "FPKM", label = "FPKM"),
               actionButton(inputId = "logFC", label = "logFC"),
               actionButton(inputId = "total",label = "logFC&FPKM")
        )
      ),
      fluidRow(
        column(3)
      ),
      fluidRow(
        column(3)
      ),
      fluidRow(
        column(12,align="center",
               plotOutput(outputId = "barplot1",height = 700, width = 1300)
        )
      ),
      fluidRow(
        column(12,align="center",
               plotOutput(outputId = "barplot2",height = 700, width = 1300)
        )
      )
    )
    
    server <- function(input, output) {
      
      
      plot_data <- reactive({
        subset(data_mean_sd, Gene %in% input$selectGeneSymbol)
      })
      
      v <- reactiveValues(barplot1 = NULL,barplot2 = NULL)
      
      observeEvent(input$FPKM, {
        v$barplot1<-ggplot(data = plot_data(), aes(x = Name, y = mean,fill=Name)) +
          geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = position_dodge(0.9), width = 0.9) +
          geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = mean - sd, ymax = mean + sd), width = .2, position = position_dodge(0.9)) +
          theme_classic2() +
          rotate_x_text(angle = 45) +
          theme(legend.position = "none") +
          labs(title = input$selectGeneSymbol, x = NULL, y = "FPKM_value") +
          theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5)) +
          theme(plot.margin = unit(c(20, 5, 1, 5), "mm"))+
          theme(axis.text.x=element_text(vjust=1,size=12))
      })
      
      observeEvent(input$logFC, {
        v$barplot2<-ggplot(data = plot_data(), aes(x = Name, y = mean,fill=Name)) +
          geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = position_dodge(0.9), width = 0.9) +
          geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = mean - sd, ymax = mean + sd), width = .2, position = position_dodge(0.9)) +
          theme_classic2() +
          rotate_x_text(angle = 45) +
          theme(legend.position = "none") +
          labs(title = input$selectGeneSymbol, x = NULL, y = "FPKM_value") +
          theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5)) +
          theme(plot.margin = unit(c(20, 5, 1, 5), "mm"))+
          theme(axis.text.x=element_text(vjust=1,size=12))
      })
      
      
      observeEvent(input$total, {
        list(
          v$barplot1<-ggplot(data = plot_data(), aes(x = Name, y = mean,fill=Name)) +
            geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = position_dodge(0.9), width = 0.9) +
            geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = mean - sd, ymax = mean + sd), width = .2, position = position_dodge(0.9)) +
            theme_classic2() +
            rotate_x_text(angle = 45) +
            theme(legend.position = "none") +
            labs(title = input$selectGeneSymbol, x = NULL, y = "FPKM_value") +
            theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5)) +
            theme(plot.margin = unit(c(20, 5, 1, 5), "mm"))+
            theme(axis.text.x=element_text(vjust=1,size=12)),
          
          v$barplot2<-ggplot(data = plot_data(), aes(x = Name, y = mean,fill=Name)) +
            geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = position_dodge(0.9), width = 0.9) +
            geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = mean - sd, ymax = mean + sd), width = .2, position = position_dodge(0.9)) +
            theme_classic2() +
            rotate_x_text(angle = 45) +
            theme(legend.position = "none") +
            labs(title = input$selectGeneSymbol, x = NULL, y = "FPKM_value") +
            theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5)) +
            theme(plot.margin = unit(c(20, 5, 1, 5), "mm"))+
            theme(axis.text.x=element_text(vjust=1,size=12))
        )
      })
      
      
      output$barplot1 <- renderPlot({
        v$barplot1
      })
      
      output$barplot2 <- renderPlot({
        v$barplot2
      })
      
      
    }
    
    # Create Shiny app ----
    shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

**It works well with the first button .Plz ignore the last 2 button .
But I wanna use the mean_data and sd_data respectively ,just like this:**

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)

mean_data <- data.frame(
  Name = c(paste0("Group_", LETTERS[1:20])),
  matx <- matrix(sample(1:1000, 1000, replace = T), nrow = 20)
)
names(mean_data)[-1] <- c(paste0("Gene_", 1:50))

sd_data <- data.frame(
  Name = c(paste0("Group_", LETTERS[1:20])),
  matx <- matrix(runif(1000, 5, 10), nrow = 20)
)
names(sd_data)[-1] <- c(paste0("Gene_", 1:50))

##
###  without combine them togather.
###
ui <- fluidPage(
  fluidRow(
    column(8,offset = 3,
           h2("Gene_FPKM Value Barplot")
    )
  ),
  fluidRow(
    column(8,offset = 3,
           selectInput(
             "selectGeneSymbol", 
             "Select Gene Symbol:", 
             choices = colnames(mean_data)[-1],
             multiple =F,
             width = 800,
             selected = "Igfbp7"
           ))
  ),
  fluidRow(
    column(8,offset = 3,
           actionButton(inputId = "FPKM", label = "FPKM"),
           actionButton(inputId = "logFC", label = "logFC"),
           actionButton(inputId = "total",label = "logFC&FPKM")
    )
  ),
  fluidRow(
    column(3)
  ),
  fluidRow(
    column(3)
  ),
  fluidRow(
    column(12,align="center",
           plotOutput(outputId = "barplot1",height = 700, width = 1300)
    )
  ),
  fluidRow(
    column(12,align="center",
           plotOutput(outputId = "barplot2",height = 700, width = 1300)
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  
  
  plot_data <- reactive({
    subset(mean_data, colnames(mean_data)[-1] %in% input$selectGeneSymbol)
  })
  
  v <- reactiveValues(barplot1 = NULL,barplot2 = NULL)
  
  observeEvent(input$FPKM, {
    v$barplot1<-ggplot(data = mean_data, aes(x = Name, y = mean_data[,input$selectGeneSymbol],fill=Name)) +
      geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = position_dodge(0.9), width = 0.9) +
      geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = mean_data[,input$selectGeneSymbol] - sd_data[,input$selectGeneSymbol], ymax = mean_data[,input$selectGeneSymbol] + sd_data[,input$selectGeneSymbol]), width = .2, position = position_dodge(0.9)) +
      theme_classic2() +
      rotate_x_text(angle = 45) +
      theme(legend.position = "none") +
      labs(title = input$selectGeneSymbol, x = NULL, y = "FPKM_value") +
      theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5)) +
      theme(plot.margin = unit(c(20, 5, 1, 5), "mm"))+
      theme(axis.text.x=element_text(vjust=1,size=12))
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$logFC, {
    v$barplot2<-ggplot(data = plot_data(), aes(x = Name, y = mean,fill=Name)) +
      geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = position_dodge(0.9), width = 0.9) +
      geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = mean - sd, ymax = mean + sd), width = .2, position = position_dodge(0.9)) +
      theme_classic2() +
      rotate_x_text(angle = 45) +
      theme(legend.position = "none") +
      labs(title = input$selectGeneSymbol, x = NULL, y = "FPKM_value") +
      theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5)) +
      theme(plot.margin = unit(c(20, 5, 1, 5), "mm"))+
      theme(axis.text.x=element_text(vjust=1,size=12))
  })
  
  
  observeEvent(input$total, {
    list(
      v$barplot1<-ggplot(data = plot_data(), aes(x = Name, y = mean,fill=Name)) +
        geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = position_dodge(0.9), width = 0.9) +
        geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = mean - sd, ymax = mean + sd), width = .2, position = position_dodge(0.9)) +
        theme_classic2() +
        rotate_x_text(angle = 45) +
        theme(legend.position = "none") +
        labs(title = input$selectGeneSymbol, x = NULL, y = "FPKM_value") +
        theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5)) +
        theme(plot.margin = unit(c(20, 5, 1, 5), "mm"))+
        theme(axis.text.x=element_text(vjust=1,size=12)),
      
      v$barplot2<-ggplot(data = plot_data(), aes(x = Name, y = mean,fill=Name)) +
        geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = position_dodge(0.9), width = 0.9) +
        geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = mean - sd, ymax = mean + sd), width = .2, position = position_dodge(0.9)) +
        theme_classic2() +
        rotate_x_text(angle = 45) +
        theme(legend.position = "none") +
        labs(title = input$selectGeneSymbol, x = NULL, y = "FPKM_value") +
        theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5)) +
        theme(plot.margin = unit(c(20, 5, 1, 5), "mm"))+
        theme(axis.text.x=element_text(vjust=1,size=12))
    )
  })
  
  
  output$barplot1 <- renderPlot({
    v$barplot1
  })
  
  output$barplot2 <- renderPlot({
    v$barplot2
  })
  
  
}

# Create Shiny app ----
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Can somebody tell me why the first actionbutton doesn't work anymore ?
Vary thankful.

EDIT: **I may be able to figure out why my code isn't working:
In my second part of codes:
my data is divided into two pieces: mean_data and sd_data
and it maybe not so suitable for me to use the below code again.**

```
plot_data <- reactive({
    subset(mean_data, colnames(mean_data)[-1] %in% input$selectGeneSymbol)
  })
```

Or any other problem here??

Please help me . Thanks.

Comment: Who can give me some help

Comment: Who can help me

Comment: @Ronak Shah   I need help .Thanks

Comment: `plot_data()` does not have columns named `mean` and `sd`.

Comment: @YBS How should I do with it ? Can you give me some code change ?

Plz. Vary thankful.

Comment: @YBS, please,I nead your help.